# Repeat adjacency selector using Less

Tags: css, less

Given the following css selectors, would it be possible to repeat the pattern an arbitrary number of times using Less?

Loops look the way to go but I can't find any examples that do something similar.

```
.page-section {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.page-section + page-section {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.page-section + page-section + page-section {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, loops in LESS can only generate complete rule-sets (selector + block), and cannot be used to generate just selectors.

Is your goal to style odd and even elements differently? Then you can avoid this looping thing with pseudo selectors:

```
.page-section                 { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
.page-section:nth-child(even) { background-color: #F7F7F7; }
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juzraai/cehwzcwp/)